# Retrieving a csv header

Tags: c#, csv

I have two seperate calls that returns a .csv file. I need to extract a couple of headers from the files depending on which one is called. The headers does not always sit in the same index, and the `CourseId` name changes to `Asset_ID` in the one call.

How can I refactor the code to make it more maintainable?

Also, I think the naming is not really good.

```
public static class CsvHeader
        {
            public struct Index
            {
                public string Email { get; set; }
                public string CompletionDate { get; set; }
                public string CourseId { get; set; }
            }
            public static Index GetCsvHeaderIndex(string[] headers)
            {
                string emailIndex = null;
                string completionDateIndex = null;

                var email = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("Email"));
                var completionDate = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("Completion"));
                var courseId = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("CourseID"));


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) emailIndex = headers.First(_ => _.Contains("Email")).Split('(', ')')[1]; /*3*/
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(completionDate)) completionDateIndex = headers.First(_ => _.Contains("Completion")).Split('(', ')')[1]; /*30*/
                var courseIdIndex = string.IsNullOrEmpty(courseId) ? 
                    headers.First(_ => _.Contains("Asset_ID")).Split('(', ')')[1] : 
                    headers.First(_ => _.Contains("CourseID")).Split('(', ')')[1];

                return new Index
                {
                    Email = emailIndex,
                    CompletionDate = completionDateIndex,
                    CourseId = courseIdIndex
                };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have some duplicated code here like for instance if `email` is not null you can get the `emailIndex` by just splitting the `email` field. The same is true for `completitionDate` and `courseId`.

This

> ```
> Email = emailIndex,
> CompletionDate = completionDateIndex,
> CourseId = courseIdIndex
> ```

looks not that good. You should rename the method variables `xxxIndex` to something better (will show in code) .

I would like to encourage you to use braces `{}` although they are optional and although you are placing the instruction on the same line as the `if`. Its intent just gets more clear.

```
public static Index GetCsvHeaderIndex(string[] headers)
{
    string email = null;
    string completionDate = null;

    var emailHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("Email"));
    var completionDateHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("Completion"));
    var courseIdHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("CourseID"));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailHeader)) { email = emailHeader.Split('(', ')')[1]; /*3*/}
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(completionDateHeader)) { completionDate = completionDateHeader.Split('(', ')')[1]; /*30*/}

    var courseId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(courseIdHeader) ?
        headers.First(_ => _.Contains("Asset_ID")).Split('(', ')')[1] :
        courseIdHeader.Split('(', ')')[1];

    return new Index
    {
        Email = email,
        CompletionDate = completionDate,
        CourseId = courseId
    };
}
```

Answer (score 12):

- Kudos for creating a struct to strong type the data, but what does `Index` mean? It's an odd term for course information. I'd look for a better name.
- Also, don't string type all the things. You have a date here, you should store it as a date.

  > ```
  > public string CompletionDate { get; set; }
  > ```

  [MSDN article on parsing dates from strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx)
- You're duplicating string literals like `"Email"`. Extract constants for these.
- You're splitting on the same character array in several places, but recreating the array for each call. Extract a local variable for `['(', ')']`

Comment: I was under the impression that the struct contains "column" heading name of the CSV file, so that `CompletionDate` is the column name, not an actual date.

Comment: You know what, you could be right about that @hangy. I guess since the method took in an array of strings, I assumed it was a misnomer.

Answer (score 8):

Mutable structs are a really bad idea. There are loads of reasons  on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

If you still want to do it have a look at what [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx)

> X DO NOT define mutable value types.

So this is not good:

```
public struct Index
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CompletionDate { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
}
```

You could make it a class, or make it immutable. I'd favour making it a class because of this (also in the MSDN guidelines)

> In general, structs can be very useful but should only be used for small, single, immutable values that will not be boxed frequently.

Your struct isn't a single value, it's a collection of 3 somewhat related values. It should definitely be a class.

You are also using a convention which I find odd:

```
headers.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Contains("Email"));
```

In several languages, e.g. I think Scala, using underscore implies the parameter can be ignored! That's not the case here and I had an additional couple of seconds of thinking "what?!" because I automatically assumed `_` meant you weren't using the parameter. Even without that convention, it's a header so you should call it so:

```
headers.FirstOrDefault(header => header.Contains("Email"));
```

Comment: +1 for the underscore, this is the first thing that stood out to me as a Haskell programmer.

Comment: I only use the underscore, when I don't care about the parameter.

Comment: @R4nc1d but if you use it, isn't that caring for the parameter? I would only use `_` to denote it isn't used at all.